# Объединить синонимичные метки [аудио] и [audio]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Объединить:

- [аудио](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%be) - 32 вопроса;
- [audio](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio) - 156 вопросов;

---

- [звук](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%ba) - 133 вопроса;

---

- [звукозапись](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c) - 13 вопросов.

(по состоянию на 19.08.2017)

Эти метки нужно объединить, так как ими уже отмечены примерно соразмерные параллельные множества вопросов.

Comment: Сюда бы еще [tag:музыка] привлечь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрел вопросы с тегом "звук"-большинство, если заменить "звук" на "audio" смысла не потеряет.

Comment: Точно. Сам удивляюсь, почему синонимизировали на две группы (аудио, audio) и (звук, sound), а не все вместе. Сейчас штатным механизмом вообще синоним звук -> аудио не предложить, ошибку пишет.

Answer (score 6):

Аудио можно и стоит объединить.

---

Звук и звукозапись все же разные вещи. Объединять не надо.

Comment: А [tag:аудио] и [tag:звук] это разные вещи (в контексте StackOverflow)?

Comment: Скорее всего нет, но тут я не в теме, и думаю что без анализа и обсуждения **звук** и **аудио** сливать не стоит. На enSO они кстати синонимизированы.

Comment: @DukeSpontaneous, звукозапись - точно отдельная метка.